# Dynamic template in Angular 13 library praject

Tags: angular

I have a library called [`@s-libs/ng-dev`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-libs/tree/master/projects/ng-dev) that includes a testing framework to simplify component tests. Once you instantiate a component during your test, it lets you change its inputs and automatically trigger everything Angular would do in production (run change detection, call `ngOnChanges()`, etc.). The library achieves this by creating a wrapper component with a dynamic template that contains your component (see code [here](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-libs/blob/1c9a71570c674867769e69aa0c78f748c8557f15/projects/ng-dev/src/lib/component-context/create-dynamic-wrapper.ts#L30)).

I'm trying an upgrade to Angular 13, and I'm getting this error on the line linked above:

```
NG1010: template must be a string
  Value could not be determined statically.
```

I've run into this before, but have been able to work around it by disabling AOT. I'm not finding a solution with Angular 13. Is there any way for a library project to have a dynamic template anymore? If not, is there some other way to achieve my same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of agonizing and trying very different solutions like implementing my own logic to reproduce Angular's behavior, I finally found a very simple answer.

Do not do this:

```
@Component({ template: buildDynamicTemplate() })
class DynamicComponent {}
```

But instead do this:

```
@Component({ template: '' })
class DynamicComponent {}

TestBed.overrideComponent(DynamicComponent, {
  set: { template: buildDynamicTemplate() },
});
```